# How to distinguish self-referential models in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `friend` model that has a self-reference to `relatedFriends`:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  friends: hasMany('friend', {inverse : 'relatedFriend'}),
  relatedFriend: belongsTo('friend', {inverse : 'friends'})
});
```

I'm running into an issue when loading a set of friends, and side-loading their related friends.

Say my route's model hook looks like this:

```
model() {
  return this.store.find(‘/friend’, {page: 1});
}
```

The server responds with 10 friend records for page 1. But, those friends have friends, and I want to sideload 3 related friends for each primary friend. So, I’ll also have 30 friends sideloaded.

Typically, for this type of response, my json would look something like

```
{
  friends: [
    {id: 1, ...
    {id: 2, ...
    {id: 2, ...
  ]
}
```

The problem is, if my response puts all these under a single `friends` key in my json, `model` won't be the single page of friends I requested; it will be all the friends (40 in this example).

How can I differentiate between the "primary" friends from my query, and the side-loaded related models?

Comment: I don't think there's an Ember Data solution to this issue, at least not yet. I think you'd have to tag your primary friends, with something like `isPrimary`, and then have your list only show the primaries.

Comment: is ember-data a hard requirement for this project ?

Comment: we're using it but, I'd be interested to hear any solution. i feel like there's a higher-level component to this question that i'm not 100% clear on

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution we came up with. Have the server put the related friends under a separate key:

```
{ 
  friends: [
    {id: 1, ...
    {id: 2, ...
  ],
  related_friends: [
    {id: 11, ...
    {id: 12, ...
  ]
}
```

Then, make a custom serializer for `related_friends` that just pushes them into the store as `friend` models:

```
// serializers/related-friend.js
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  extract(store, primaryModelClass, payload) {
    const relatedFriends = payload.related_friends;

    // load any related_friends as friends
    if (relatedFriends) {
      relatedFriends.forEach(attrs => store.pushPayload('friend', {
        friend: attrs
      }));

      delete payload.related_friends;
    }

    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Now, the route's `model` represents our query, but all sideloaded data has been appropriately pushed into the store.